# Lookup function does not work within the Profile for Puppet

Tags: puppet, lookup, hiera

I am getting the following error in the event viewer on my node during a puppet run. I suspect the issue is with incorrect lookup function in my profile.

```
Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER: Server Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Resource Statement, Scconfig::Coserveradmin[SomeSettings]:
parameter 'parameterA' expects a String value, got Undef
parameter 'parameterB' expects a String value, got Undef
parameter 'parameterC' expects a String value, got Undef
parameter 'parameterD' expects a String value, got Undef
```

`coserveradmin` is a `define` resource with all string parameters. I would like to do lookup of values from a Json file

```
{
    "SASettings" : {
        "Watchdog" : {
            "ParameterA"            : "somevalue",
            "ParameterB"            : "somevalue"
        },
        "Serversettings" : {
            "ParameterC"            : "somevalue",
            "ParameterD"            : "somevalue",

        },
        "GeneralSettings" : {
            "ParameterE"            : "somevalue",
            "ParameterF"            : "somevalue",

        },
        "customsettings_prod" : {
            "ParameterG"            :"somevalue",
            "ParameterH"            : "%{facts.hostname}.example-cloud.com"
        },
        "customsettings_dev" : {
            "ParameterI"            :"",
            "ParameterK"            : "%{facts.hostname}.example.net"
        }
    }
}
```

In my hiera.yaml file I have defined the name and path to the json file.

```
- name: "Desired Some Settings"
    path: "default/serveradmin.json"
```

In profile I have the following code .

```
    class profile::scconfig_someprofile_a {
                .
                .
                .
                $hname= $::facts['hostname']
                $mac= "${facts['macaddress'].delete(':')}"
                $adminpropeties = lookup('SASettings')

               if $hname=~someregex {
                           scconfig::coserveradmin{ 'SomeSettings':
                           property1 => $adminpropeties['customsettings_prod.ParameterG'],
                           property2 => $adminproperties['Watchdog.ParameterA'],
                           property3 => $adminproperties['Watchdog.ParameterB'],
                           property4 => $adminproperties['Serversettings.ParameterC'],
                           .
                           .
                           .
                           .
                           and so on
                           .
                           macaddress => $mac,

               }
               elsif $hname=~someregex {
                           scconfig::coserveradmin{ 'SomeSettings':
                           property1 => $adminpropeties['customsettings_dev.ParameterI'],
                           property2 => $adminproperties['Watchdog.ParameterA'],
                           property3 => $adminproperties['Watchdog.ParameterB'],
                           property4 => $adminproperties['Serversettings.ParameterC'],
                           .
                           .
                           .
                           .
                           and so on
                           .
                           macaddress => $mac,

               }
```

Also adding the code for the "define" resource as requested.

```
define scconfig::coserveradmin(
    String $Property1,
    String $Property2,
    String $Property3,
    String $Property4,
    .
    .
    .
    String $macaddress,

  ) {

  $dscmoduleversion = lookup('requires.modules.codsc.version')
  if $dscmoduleversion != '' {
      $module = {
          'name'    => 'codsc',
          'version' => $dscmoduleversion,
      }
  }else{
      $module = 'codsc'
  }

  $configname1='someconfig1'
  $configname2='someconfig2'
  $configname3='someconfig3'

  dsc { 'someconfig1':
    require       => lookup('requires.cloudopssoftware'),
    resource_name => 'Someresourcename',
    module        => $module,
    properties    => {
      configname         => $configname1,
      Prop1   => $Property1,
      Prop2   => $Property2,
      Prop3   =>$Property3,
    },
  }
  dsc { 'someconfig2':
   require       => lookup('requires.cloudopssoftware'),
   resource_name => 'someresourcename2',
   module        => $module,
   properties    => {
      configname    => $configname2,
            Prop1   => $Property4,
            Prop2   => $Property5,
            Prop3   =>$Property6,
    },
  }

 dsc { 'someconfig3':
   require       => lookup('requires.cloudopssoftware'),
   resource_name => 'someresourcename3',
   module        => $module,
   properties    => {
      configname    => $configname3,
            Prop1   => $Property6,
            Prop2   => $Property7,
            Prop3   =>$Property8,
            .
            .
            .
            Propn   => $macaddress
         },
       }
```

Please note that the last property which is the macaddress is evaluated within the profile class therefore I don't see any error for it.

Any ideas what could be the issue.

Comment: Could you post the code for `scconfig::coserveradmin`, please? The problem is most likely with its parameter list

Comment: I have updated the main description with the code for define resource.

Comment: Thanks. Two of the parameters to `coserveradmin` have double dollar signs, for example `$$Property2`. Is that right?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo in my post. Fixed it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I suspect the issue is with incorrect lookup function in my profile.

That does not appear to be the case.  If your `lookup()` call were not successfully looking up and returning a hash then you would get a different error when you tried to extract values.

I guess it's possible that you're retrieving the wrong hash -- which would be a matter of your hiera configuration and / or data, not the `lookup()` call itself -- but whether it's the right hash or the wrong one, the syntax you are trying to use to extract the data from it is not matched to the hash structure presented in the question.  For example, this expression

> ```
> $adminpropeties['customsettings_prod.ParameterG']
> ```

attempts to retrieve the value whose key is `'customsettings_prod.ParameterG'`, but the data presented contain no such key.

What you seem to want is

```
 $adminpropeties['customsettings_prod']['ParameterG']
```

That extracts the value having key `'customsettings_prod'`, and, that value being a hash itself, extracts *its* value associated with key `'ParameterG'`.

Alternatively, you may find [the `dig()` function](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/6.10/function.html#dig) convenient for extracting data from nested data structures such as yours:

```
dig($adminpropeties, 'customsettings_prod', 'ParameterG')
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this out and will let you know in a day or two.

Comment: Thank you!I tried the 'dig' function and it is working perfectly. Just what I need. However, I have another question regarding define scconfig::coserveradmin. I have 2 different nodes running different profiles and they call the same define resource. Not all properties are required to be set on first node and vice versa. I was hoping if  there was a way of making some Parameters of the Define resource as mandatory but couldn't find a way to do it. Or create define resource for each node which is not preferred way.What are your thoughts?

Comment: @tafz, my first thought is that a separate question should be posed *as* a separate question, provided that you cannot discover an answer for yourself, and that the question meets our normal guidelines.

Comment: Thanks I found my answer.